# How to calculate the volume of material required to create a Hollow cube

Tags: c++

I want to calculate the volume of material required to create a hollow cube of 10mm*10mm*10mm with thickness 1mm. I am able to get the volume of hollow cube using the following code but i am not getting how to get the volume of material required to create a hollow cube. I think this is a silly question but i didn't a suitable answer for this. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Volume           // Class definition to calculate the volume of the hollow 
{
    public:

    Volume(){};

    double cubeVolume(double length)
    {
        double volume= length * length * length;
        return volume;
    }

    double cube(double num)
    {
        return (num*num*num);
    }

    double getHollowCubeVolume(double length, double thickness)
    {
        double outerVol=cubeVolume(length);
        double innerVol= cube((length-(thickness+thickness)));
    
        double HollowCubeVolume = (cube(outerVol)-cube(innerVol));
    
        return HollowCubeVolume;
    }
};

int main()
{
   cout << "Volume of the material required for hollow cube" << endl; 

   Volume volObj;
   cout<<"Volume of material used to create a hallow cube: "<<volObj.getHollowCubeVolume(10,1)<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to explain your code to your rubber-duck. Pay special attention to how often you apply `^3`

Comment: Your calculation of `HollowCubeVolume` is wrong.   Don't pass `outerVol` and `innerVol` to `cube()` - just calculate the difference.

Comment: Also, none of your functions should be (non-static) member functions.

Comment: What's the difference between `cube()` and `cubeVolume()` functions?

Comment: If you had a calculator, how would you calculate it?

Comment: Shouldn't the volume of (inner) face be removed too?

Answer (score 0):

First, please read and think about the comments on your question. Those are good suggestions.

Then, here's a solution (but please don't just use it blindly.) You just need two functions like this:

```
double cube (double x) {
    return x * x * x;
}

double hollow_cube_volume (double outer_side, double thickness) {
    double inner_side = outer_side - 2 * thickness;
    if (inner_side < 0)
        inner_side = 0.0;
    double volume = cube(outer_length) - cube(inner_side);
    return volume; 
}
```

That's it.

The formula in your head for doing this is probably correct; you are just getting confused in implementing it. Also, there is no need for a class here.

I also added a check for a too-thick material (e.g. when we have a 10mm cube and specify a 6mm thickness.) Checking for user errors and mistakes is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly follow the comments. It seems that it was just a silly mistake.
However the error is in the following function-

```
double getHollowCubeVolume(double length, double thickness)
{
    double outerVol=cubeVolume(length);
    double innerVol= cube(length-(thickness+thickness));
    
    double HollowCubeVolume = outerVol-innerVol;  //Just take the difference.
                                                  // No need to pass them in cube function again.
    
    return HollowCubeVolume;
}
```